# Reproduzir AudioClip com .wav em outro pacote JAVA

Tags: java

Utilizo esse código para reproduzir sons na minha aplicação, porém só reproduz o áudio se ele estiver na pasta do projeto, e não dentro de um pacote. E caso eu exporte meu projeto criando um .jar ele não inclui os arquivos de mídia. 
Já tentei mudar o caminho adicionando o pacote, neste caso, sons, mais não reproduz "/sons/audio.wav". 
Agradeço.

```
try {
    AudioClip c = Applet.newAudioClip(new File("audio.wav").toURL());
    c.play();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Acredito que o problema seja a hierarquia de pacotes. Se possivel, poste uma imagem de como está. Utilizando File, o java vai sempre procurar o arquivo no sistema de arquivos do SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se estiver na pasta de recursos você pode usar o `getResourceAsStream`:

```
...
AudioClip c = Applet.newAudioClip(Principal.class.getResource("/recurso/audio.wav").toURI().toURL());
c.play();
...
```

[image: Estrutura]

Comment: AudioClip a = Applet.newAudioClip(ControleAtendimento.class.getResourceAsStream("/recurso/audio.wav").toURI().toString());

Comment: Da um erro, pede pra fazer um cast, mais em seguida fica errado.

Comment: @JesséSantos não tem o `toString()` veja agora como fica

Comment: Não deu, ainda sim pede que seja feito um cast, do tipo File, quando faço da erro.

Comment: Você está usando a classe `Applet` de qual pacote?

Comment: import java.applet.Applet;
import java.applet.AudioClip;

Comment: @JesséSantos você usou exatamente o código que eu passei ali? Eu não estou usando nada de classe `File` como você está informando.

Comment: @diegofm adicionei a estrutura

Comment: @Sorack o comentario foi pro OP, comentei no lugar errado hehe

Comment: Amigo, deu muito certo. Obrigado pela ajuda, recopiei o seu código e consegui. Valeu mesmo

Comment: @JesséSantos não esqueça de marcar a resposta como correta para que possa ser utilizada por pessoas com dúvida similar

Comment: Atualmente usa o quê? Está ultrapassada esse Audioclip.

Answer (score 1):

Se você tem um diretório a partir da raiz do projeto, o caminho correto é:

```
"sons/audio.wav"
```

Observe que está sem a barra.
Recomendo fazer testes com a classe `File`, criando um arquivo e pegando o caminho completo ou verificando se existe:

```
File f = new File("sons/audio.wav");
System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
System.out.println(f.exists())
```

Comment: Testei, e não executou.